# Bootstrap failing to load from maxcdn ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, http, cdn, integrity

I'm using Bootstrap in my application from MAXCDN but sometimes it fails to load and gives me two reasons which I can't figure out why.

```
(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET // min.css

(failed) net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE // min.js
```

I'm using the CDN urls with the integrity and source from the bootstrap cdn

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
```

If I open this this url it works fine. This is happening on local and on a staging `https` environment.

Comment: Have you had any luck solving this? I'm experiencing a similar problem intermittently with fontawesome and jquery.

Comment: I also have the same problem with Symfony application on staging and production.  Also intermittent, also Maxcdn

Comment: We currently narrowed it down to being our internet provider. Very strange.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but had a similar issue. Worked around it by keeping a local server copy and used as a failover if js/css scripts don't load from CDN. There are a few asset loaders that enable this -or- you can roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of a firewall, or even by your Internet Provider (there is similar question here: https://superuser.com/q/1110801/214156).

However, if it is something you cannot control, maybe you can try to override the URLs using a proxy like Charles or a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an issue with the hosting. When I changed to an IIS server that didn't have a Plesk panel installed.

The site where Plesk was installed, required that the server settings for "Web Application Firewall (ModSecurity)" be loosened, or removed.

You can either remove them (lowers security) or change or customize rulesets specific to the errors you see being reported.